# Should low-rep edit suggestions be rate limited?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Today, I noticed a large number of edit suggestions (to tag wikis as it happens, but I don't think that's relevant) by a user who doesn't have the reputation yet to make unsupervised edits. More than I could vote on to moderate (a limit I was a little surprised to hit, but fair enough). Should they have been “encouraged” by a rate limit to do fewer edit suggestions in a day? After all, while editing is good, asking and answering questions is far better for SO overall.

Comment: Are they filling up the edit queue faster then the edits are being aproved?   Are the edits good edits?   E.g. is this a problem.

Comment: @Ian: In general, the system seems to be working, especially for question and answer edits. Tag wikis seem to be having more of an issue though, especially as they seem to generate multiple submissions per editing session (don't know why).

Comment: I wish the `improve` button was hooked up for the tag wiki edits. I saw many edits today that were _mostly_ good with exceptions that I could have easily corrected -- but were thrown clear into the `reject` pile due to those glaring exceptions.

Comment: Someone could well find a set of related tags with poor wiki text so the fact that edits from a single user are "branched" is to be expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is rate limited, if you reject bad edits, bad suggesters are auto banned from suggesting for a week.

Comment: But is there a limit to how many edits a person can have available to review at any given time?

Comment: @Gabe: Why would you want to limit good edits?

Comment: @John: Who says they're good edits?

Comment: @Gabe: If the user has been making bad edits, they can't make any more, so presumably, if they're still editing, they're probably good editors and therefore producing good edits.

Comment: @John: Even the best flaggers only get something like 50 flags a day to limit the workload for mods. Presumably you'd want to limit the workload for reviewers by only letting so many items be up for review at once.

Comment: @Gabe: SO has what, 5 ♦ mods?  SO has [*over 7000*](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/97377/who-has-the-edit-privilege) people who can review edits.  Assuming 10000 edits are made every day, that's not even 2 reviews per person per day.  How little of a workload do they need?

Comment: @Gabe: A common situation is that there will be 2 or 3 edits made by one person to a tag wiki. Of those, one will be good and the other(s) not so good. Length is not necessarily a good indicator; too often the longer suggestions are lengthened by the addition of puffery. When you get a person editing a whole bunch of tag wikis in quick succession – what prompted my Q – there's rapidly far too much for any normal editor to review by themselves.

Comment: @waffles: Tag wiki edits seem to end up with multiple submissions a lot. Are there really large numbers of people doing multiple submits per tag wiki edit? A few, OK, but apparently that seems to be the majority behavior, which suggests that there might be a usability issue there…

Comment: @Donal: I just went to the review page, and there were 10 pending edits, all from one user ([orftz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/603891/orftz).  I rejected one (one letter trivia) and left the rest - I'd previously done enough of his edits for one day (some accept, some reject).  There are a couple of other people I've seen a lot of in the 'to be reviewed' list, again with mixed results (some accept, some reject).  I wonder if there needs to be a rate limit on submissions - as in the question.  Maybe 30 per day...